# Compare two columns and copy value to another cell in same row

Tags: excel, vba, compare

I need one modification of code below. The point is that this code compare values of two whole columns. What i need is to compare cell values only in same row, and if value is same copy it to new column, for example:

```
   A  B       C <- copy column
   1  1       1
   2  3       
   3  3       3
   4  2
   5  5       5
```

-> values in C2 and C4 are not copied because there is not same value in columns corresponding rows.

```
Sub Compare()

Dim CompareRange As Variant, To_Be_Compared As Variant, x As Variant, y As Variant

Range("C2").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Set To_Be_Compared = Range("C2:" & Selection.Address)

Range("K2").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Set CompareRange = Range("K2:" & Selection.Address)

To_Be_Compared.Select

    For Each x In Selection
        For Each y In CompareRange
             If x = y Then x.Offset(0, 1) = x 
        Next y
    Next x
End Sub
```

Hope you can understand me.

Cheers,
Dev.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to avoid using select, without activating your sheet first, because if your workbook is showing another sheet, you will get an error.

Or you can do the same with the range object.

```
dim Rng_to_Be_Compared as range
set Rng_to_Be_Compared = thisworkbook.worksheets(<worksheet name>).range("c2")
set Rng_to_Be_Compared = Rng_to_Be_Compared.resize(Rng_to_Be_Compared.end(xlDown).row - Rng_to_Be_Compared . row)
```

Then you can use a variable as an offset

```
dim comp_offset as integer, write_Offset as integer
write_Offset = 9
comp_offset = 8

dim cel as range

for each cel in rng_to_ba_compared.rows
    if cel = cel.offset(,comp_offset) then
        cel.offset(,write_offset).value = cel.value
   end if
next cel
```

here you go